# Multiple bulb pendant lamp, grounding wire for metal fixture

Tags: light-fixture, grounding, metal

Hypothetically speaking, if a person is adding a ground wire to a 3 prong plug in pendant fixture with multiple bulbs in parallel  and the body of the pendant is metal, does there need to be a ground wire to EACH bulb socket  or just a ground wire to one of them/connecting to the metal body?

Hypothetical #1 - If each lamp socket has ground screws, this would make sense to ground each one if necessary, or, only one if all metal is connected?

Hypothetical #2 - if the lamp sockets are only 2 wire  and a ground is being added to be in contact with the metal body, does a ground only need to be connected "once" or  does it need to be run to all sockets?

Comment: Pictures would help - take the [tour] and [edit] to include some. "Pendant" covers many things - if the fixture is a solid hunk of metal that hangs, one connection is fine. If sockets dangle by individual chains, modern practice is to thread a bare ground wire through the chain to make a solid connection to the dangling bit at the end of the chain.

Comment: @Ecnerwal perfect, that actually makes sense, and I realize I wasn't very clear with the description.  I believe you answered what I was wondering though, as it would be one complete piece of metal with the bulbs / sockets affixed to/inside it.  It seemed that with the entire body being metal, that one single ground (for safety, for the metal body) would work.  Though that's a good point, if the bulbs are dangling from wire or suspended, that each would/should have a ground wire.  Thanks again for the insight!

Comment: let me see if I got the markup for pics, I was curious about designs like this, make of metal pipe, as it seems no one ever bothers to ground them, or include info on grounding them, if they are freestanding.  I know this image looks hardwired and not corded, but hypothetically - if it were corded.  ![example light](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5f/b4/34/5fb434c7a11660e907b3124c0f802194.jpg)

Comment: Simply drag & drop images into the text [edit] box and the site will take care of uploading & hosting them for you, no need to worry about markup (and extra `!`) at all. If the image is already uploaded somewhere, just click the "sun & mountain" icon and paste the URL to the .jpg into the box that pops up.